# Adding "radio" functionality to buttons when using a custom binder in Rivets.js with Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, rivets.js

I am using Rivets.js to bind elements to my model. I am using Bootstrap by Twitter for design, and have set up three buttons to choose from the values 1, 2 and 3 (functionally equivalent to radio buttons).

I have set up three buttons in a button group like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" id="input_level" data-toggle="model.level">
    <button data-toggle-value="1" class="btn active">One</button>
    <button data-toggle-value="2" class="btn">Two</button>
    <button data-toggle-value="3" class="btn">Three</button>
</div>
```

I have added a custom `toggle` binder like so:

```
rivets.binders.toggle = function(el,value){
    $(el).find('button[data-toggle-value="' + value + '"]')
        .addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
}
```

This updates the button state like it should, but doesn't work the other way - i.e. there is no event bound to the button click event. I want to generalize this to Rivets.js so I don't have to add a click event to each button group in the form in the Backbone view.

Is this basic functionality in Rivets, and if so, how do I set it up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After studying the Rivets.js annotated source, I found the solution after a while (I'm not using CoffeeScript, so it was a bit of a hassle to read):

I replaced this piece of original code in my question:

```
rivets.binders.toggle = function(el,value){
    $(el).find('button[data-toggle-value="' + value + '"]')
        .addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
}
```

With this:

```
rivets.binders.toggle = {
    publishes: true,
    bind: function(el){
        $(el).on('click', 'button:not(.active)', _.bind(function(e){
            this.model.set(this.keypath, $(e.currentTarget).data('toggle-value'));
        }, this));
    },
    unbind: function(el){
        $(el).off('click', 'button:not(.active)');
    },
    routine: function(el,value){
        $(el).find('button[data-toggle-value="' + value + '"]')
            .addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }
};
```

The initial code is now under `rivets.binders.toggle.routine` instead of `rivets.binders.toggle`.

Comment: But any suggestions for a better way to solve this is welcome!